# Show that or disprove that $k+1 ≤ \chi(H) ≤ k+4$.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, coloring

Given $P = (V_P, E_P) $, which is planar graph, and $ G=(V_G, E_G)$, which is a graph with  $\chi(G) = k$.

Let's construct a new graph $H$ out of the vertices from $V_P \cup  V_G$. The edges should contain all edges from $P$ and $G$ and additionally edges from where the vertices from $V_P$ to $V_G$ connect.

Show that or disprove that $k+1 ≤ \chi(H) ≤ k+4$.

Any ideas? This seems to be not that hard, but I have no idea how to prove this properly.

Comment: So to be clear, every vertex of $V_P$ is adjacent to every vertex of $V_G$? If so, try to make a colouring for $H$ using the fact that every planar graph can be coloured with between 1 and 4 colours.

Comment: @BrandonduPreez that was my idea as well. But how would that look like? I am a little bit lost on how to approach a proper "proof" on this, beside stating just the theorem. Would be awesome if you could give me some kind of example.

Comment: A nice example to work through is where $P$ is a tree and $G$ is some complete graph $K_n$, because then it will be easy to see why you need at least $\chi(G) + 1$ colours {in this case, actually, $\chi(G) + 2$}.

Answer (score 1):

As an aside, your construction of $H$ is often called the [join](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/GraphJoin.html) $H = P + G$ of the graphs $P$ and $G$. Notice that both $G$ and $P$ are subgraphs of $H$.

Let $\chi(H) = k$. So we need to show that $k + 1 \leq \chi(H) \leq k + 4$.

**Part 1:** $k + 1 \leq \chi(H)$.
We need to show that no matter proper colouring we give to $H$, it has at least $k+1$ colours. I've given a proof of this in the spoiler below (click it to see)

> Let $c : V(H) \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ be any proper colouring of $H$ (so assign a number to each vertex such that no two adjacent vertices have the same colour). If we restrict ourselves to only looking at the subgraph $G$, then $c$ must also properly colour these vertices. So at least $\chi(G) = k$ colours appear in $G$. Now let $u$ be a vertex in $P$. Since $u$ is adjacent to every vertex of $G$, it must get a different colour from every vertex of $G$. So the total number of colours in $c$ is at least $k+1$, so $\chi(H) \geq k+1$.

**Part 2:** $\chi(H) \leq k + 4$.
All we need to do to show this is true is to find some proper colouring of $H$ using at most $k+4$ colours. I'll give a way to find one in the spoiler.

> Since $P$ is planar, we can colour it using the proper colouring $c_P$ using the 4 colours $\{a, b, c, d\}$, by the Four Colour Theorem. Since $\chi(G) = k$, we can give it a colouring $c_G$ using the colours $\{1, 2, \dots, k\}$. So one way to colour $H$ is to give every vertex $u$ of $P$ the "colour" (i.e., letter from $a$ to $d$) $c_P(u)$, and give every vertex $v$ of $G$ the colour (i.e., number from $1$ to $k$) $c_G(v)$. Every edge of $H$ is either an edge of $P$, or an edge of $G$, or an edge from $P$ to $G$, so no two adjacent vertices get the same colour. We have only used the colours $1, 2, \dots, k$ and $a, b, c, d$, so we have used at most $k+4$ colours.